# Is there any difference in meaning between "play with someone", "play against someone" and "play someone"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *play with someone*, *play against someone* and *play someone*? For example:

> I have a ping pong table. Do you want to **play with me**.
>
> I have a ping pong table. Do you want to **play against me**.
>
> I have a ping pong table. Do you want to **play me**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Play with me” does not include the competitive element.

As it is understood to be a competitive game, “play against me” sounds like overkill to me, and, were I inviting someone to compete, I’d simply use “play me”.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid all of them for reasons I give below.

I would normally say

> Would you like a game?
> Do you fancy a game?

Play against sounds too competitive and I would avoid both the others unless I knew the person very well since they have a sexual overtone. I think play me may be more US specific, it sounds unnatural to me but play with me is OK in British English subject to the caveat I raise.